# Most efficient way of artifact copy?

Tags: java, file, maven, copy

I'm software delivery engineer, I have requirement to deliver artifact as a product to the customer. Using maven I can  download artifact from the repository. Once download artifact I need to copy these artifact to the specific folder location What would be the best way to do that?

How to do that using java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are delivering a finished product to a customer, I would strongly recommend you package the deliverable using Maven itself, perhaps the [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/). This will allow you to produce a structured output including binaries, dependencies, docs, etc.

Once you have configured the release format to suit your needs, you can give customers the result of your Maven build. No need to then worry about how to do this in Java.

Comment: You can also use the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to zip the product with all its dependencies.